# Uploading App Preview Video on iTunes Connect later

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to submit an App update for my App which is already in the AppStore. I also want to add an App Preview Video with my new update.

The [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10) states this:

> App preview properties are locked, and so they can only be edited when
>   the app is in an editable state.

Does this mean that I have to submit the App Preview Video with the App Binary itself?

My video is not ready yet and will take some time. Can I submit my app now and add the video later when the App state is in `Waiting For Review`?

Comment: You can add video or edit some info related to your app like screenshots,description and other metadata info, while your app is in Waiting for Review. When it goes to InReview state, you wont be able to edit or change any info related to your app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit all meta-data information while your app is in **Waiting For Review** status.

But it'll be better to upload the Video and Binary together, because you can't tell when your app status will become **In Review** status.

Comment: I am assuming it usually takes at least 1-2 days for the iTunes Connect Team to take the app in for the Review, till then my video will be prepared and I'll save some queue time there.

Comment: @AnujRajput: Can't say anything on the time. My previous app update only took 7 Hrs for In Review status.

Comment: [Midhun MP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp) You're right. It took me 2 hours once :(

When was this last update you sent?

Comment: @AnujRajput: December first week. I uploaded two app updates same day. 1 took 7 Hrs and another 2 Hrs

Comment: @AnujRajput: You are welcome, also FYI till December 29 iTunes connect won't accept any build. Happy coding.

Comment: Psst! They opened iTunes Connect last night. (Dec 28) Don't tell anyone ;)

Comment: @AnujRajput: Wow : I won't anyone shhh ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your all meta-data when it in "waiting for review" status.
If it in "In review" you can not change meta-data and screen shot,video as well.

and Once your app is "ready for sale" you can not change  screenshot,video.
If you wanted to change then you need to give update for next.

"Beginning January 9 [2013], app screenshots will be locked in iTunes Connect once your app has been approved. New screenshots may be uploaded when you submit a binary for an update to an existing app or a new app."